# Xcode throwing error "reading dependency file"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was progressing with making my app and today morning when I opened my project to check how it is running on the simulator. Xcode threw in some random errors and I'm not able to run my app on the simulator.

It is saying that [**The file “FatGo / Home Workouts” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to v…**] and it is showing 5 errors namely:

[image: errors]

Comment: have you tried Shift + Cmd + K to clear all data and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try deleting derived data in following way?

1. Press `CMD + ,` in Xcode
2. Go to `Locations`
3. Next to `Derived Data` press on `arrow` (finder will be opened)
4. Go to `DerivedData` directory in finder
5. Delete your project under `DerivedData`
6. Build the app again

Comment: I built the app again. Although I saved it with a different name this time and it worked perfectly. I made 2-3 apps before with the above notorious name, maybe those files didn't delete properly and hence Xcode might be having problem in compiling.